# Having issues looking at all old versions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, excel, versioning

I've been trying to look at older versions of a file but keep getting this error? Any idea what it's happening?[image]

I've looked at the source of the document within Excel and it's looking for a copy "(2)" of the file but that's not what the file is called. I'm not sure how to fix it. 
 [image]